# Where to learn about expectation

Tags: references, expected-value

Now, this might sound a little weird, but let me explain. When one has a random variable (like an estimator), one often cares about two things. The first is concentration -- now, I have seen many books on the concentration of measure and in the end, there are many cases where this is relatively easy. The second thing is the expectation of the random variable. However, I have never seen a "book on expectation".

So it is relatively clear what to read if I want to become a "master of concentration inequalities". However, what should I read and understand to become "master of working with expectations of random variables"?

Comment: There are plenty of books or parts of books about [expectation](https://www.google.com/search?q=statistics+expectation+book) or [central tendency](https://www.google.com/search?q=statistics+central+tendency+book)

Comment: Thank you for the link on the central tendency, I will look into it. As for the books on expectation, there is not a single book which would be "on expectation"